# AlertDialog created multiple times Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Iam Showing a AlertDialog on Device Shake. The issue is that when I shake the device the AlertDialog shows twice. Hence, if I dismiss the AlertDialog, the top one gets dismissed but there is one still showing after that behind the first one.

Also, Iam showing the same AlertDialog from another section of code where it is shown on a button click which works fine.

All of this is done within a ViewPager.

How can I avoid this scenario?

Here is my code:-

```
@Override
public void onShake(float force) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    showDialog(timeString, "Confirm .");
}

public void showDialog(String timeString, String title)
    {

        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMessage("Reaching at:"+" "+ timeString+"?");

        builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Do nothing

            }
        });

        builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
            {
                // Do nothing but close the dialog

                new AddStatusTask().execute();

            }

        });


        builder.show();
    }
```

Comment: where are you dismiss your dialog?

Comment: check if dialog in not already showing then show it..else not

Comment: @iam stack Any Answer that worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

check like this

```
if (alertDialog != null && !alertDialog.isShowing()) {
        //then show your dialog..else not 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 
     builder.show();

use

```
// create alert dialog
alertDialog = builder.create();

// show it
alertDialog.show();
```

and check here like

```
@Override
   public void onShake(float force) 
  {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

 if(alertDialog != null && !alertDialog.isShowing()){
showDialog(timeString, "Confirm .");
```

}
      }

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your code. But now the AlertDialog doesnt show at all. As I mentioned in the question, Iam showing this AlertDialog in a fragment within a ViewPager.

Answer (score 0):

Remove line alertDialog.show(); from showDialog(..) method and use like this .

```
@Override
public void onShake(float force) 
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
 showDialog(timeString, "Confirm .");
 if(alertDialog != null && !alertDialog.isShowing()){
  alertDialog.show();
} }
```

Comment: This doesn't work either. It still gives the same output

Comment: the problem is, when the fragment in ViewPager is shown for the first time and i shake the device.,the alert dialog works fine and dismisses properly. But again if shake the phone while the fragment is showing the problem occurs

Answer (score 0):

I used a variable called alertCounter. I first initialize alertCounter to be 0. When I needed to show the alert, I increment alertCounter by 1. When dismissing the dialog, I decrement the alertCounter by 1. I only show the dialog when the alertCounter < 1.

Declare and initialize alertCounter as an instance variable.

```
int alertCounter = 0;
```

Then, create the dialog.

```
public void createDialog(){
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Shake Detected");
    builder.setMessage("Message");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            //do something
            alertCounter--;
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            //do something
            alertCounter--;         
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    alert = builder.create();
}
```

Then show it whenever necessary only once.

```
public void showCrashDialog(){
    if(alertCounter < 1){
        alert.show();
        alertCounter++;
    }
}
```